# Why some Spock Grails Integration Specs need clear before checking DataBase results

Tags: grails, grails-orm, integration-testing, spock

I'm a Spock fan and I try to show everyone about its wonders. But most of the times they come back to me and tell me that they can't make it work with IntegrationSpecs in Grails for transactional services. I had this trouble myself a lot of times and always managed to solved it with a trick or two but now I want to know what is going on.

I made a simple example where I need to clear the session before any query to the database return me the expected behavior.

```
static transactional = false

def cleanup() {
    deleteAllBills()
}

@Unroll
void "update all opened Bills to status CLOSED"() {
    given:
    createAndSaveOpenBill()

    when:
    def rowsUpdated = billTransitionService."$method"()

    and:
    if (clearSession) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()
    }

    then:
    rowsUpdated == 1

    then:
    def bills = Bill.findAll()
    bills.status.every { it == 'CLOSED' }

    where:
    desc                 | method                       | clearSession
    'where and update'   | 'transitionOpenToClosed'     | false
    'where and update'   | 'transitionOpenToClosed'     | true
    'findAll and update' | 'transitionOpenToClosedLoop' | false
    'findAll and update' | 'transitionOpenToClosedLoop' | true
}

@Transactional
def createAndSaveOpenBill() {
    new Bill(status: 'OPEN').save(failOnError: true)
}

@Transactional
void deleteAllBills() {
    Bill.findAll()*.delete()
}
```

and the service is really easy as well

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class BillTransitionService {

    def transitionOpenToClosed() {
        Bill.where { status == 'OPEN' }.updateAll(status: 'CLOSED')
    }

    def transitionOpenToClosedLoop() {
        def billsToClose = Bill.findAllByStatus('OPEN')
        billsToClose*.status = 'CLOSED'
        return billsToClose.size()
    }
}
```

The first test fails and the other three works perfectly. This example was made with Grails 2.4.4 but I had the same problem with almost every version since 2.2.3.

The code is online here if you want to try it yourself https://github.com/juandiegoh/grails-spock-transactions

**EDIT:** I implemented the same tests with GroovyTestCase and with JUnit 4 and the problem continues, you can check it out on Github. So is not a Spock problem by itself. I would love to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Is this problem specific to Spock? Does the same test expressed in JUnit work?

Comment: I will have to do more tests, actually I mostly use Spock. I will try with another one.

Comment: I did the test with GroovyTestCase and JUnit 4 and it does not work.